# MySQL in Qt 5 Ubuntu, QMYSQL driver not loaded

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-14.04, qt5.5

There are may posts about this, and I've tried everything without any luck.

The error message I get is:

QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded

QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QPSQL QPSQL7

The code is just a simple connection-test(db, username and password not shown here):

```
#include "database.h"

#include <QApplication>
#include <QtSql>
#include <QSqlDriver>

database::database()
{

    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
        db.setHostName("xxx:3306");
        db.setDatabaseName("xxxx");
        db.setUserName("xxx");
        db.setPassword("xxx");
        bool ok = db.open();

        if(ok){

                     qDebug() << QCoreApplication::libraryPaths();

        }else{

        }
}
```

In my .pro I have the following:

```
QT += qml quick widgets svg core gui multimedia sql
QTPLUGIN += qsqlmysql
CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    database.cpp

RESOURCES += \
    qml/qml.qrc \
    fonts/fonts.qrc\
    images/images.qrc

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/mysql
```

main.cpp just calls the database.

In the folder /opt/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers there are these files:

libqsqlite.so  libqsqlmysql.so  libqsqlpsql.so

In the folder /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ I also have

libmysqlclient.so libmysqlclient.so.18

**Does anyone know how to solve this problem?**